# How to recall the API request after getting the refresh token?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, access-token, refresh-token

I am trying to recall the API request after getting the refresh token from the API.
Having issue in recall the same API request.
It shows invalid access token error while running this api.
how to fix this issue.

How to recall the get API request to get the access token .

```js
  Future<http.Response> _getAPIById(String pathURL) async {
    try {
      final Uri uri = Uri.http(ApiConstants.baseUrl, pathURL);
      print(uri);
      print(accessToken);
      http.Response response = await _ioClient.get(
        uri,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken!
        },
      );
      if (response.statusCode != 200) {
        print("Status Not Ok");
        print(response.body);
        if (response.statusCode == 401) {
          await  refreshAccessToken();
          print("Status code 401 called");
          Future.delayed(
              Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                  () async {
                    return await _ioClient.get(
                      uri,
                      headers: {
                        HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
                        'x-access-token': 'Bearer ' + accessToken!
                      },
                    );
                  });
        }
      } else if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print("Ok");
        print(response.body);
        return response;
      }
      print(response.body);
      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      throw Exception('Error occurred');
    }
  }
  
  
  
   Future<String>  refreshAccessToken() async {
    Map<String, String> requestBody = {'refresh_token': refreshToken!};
    final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(
            ApiConstants.baseUrlWithHttp + ApiConstants.refreshAccessToken),
        body: requestBody,
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
        encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8"));
    print("refreshAccessToken");
    print(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      status = true;
      var decodedData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      accessToken = decodedData['accessToken'];
      refreshToken = decodedData['refreshToken'];
    }
    return response.body;
  }
```

How to fix this issue? Help me with the solution.

Comment: You are running your 2nd call with refreshed token after a delay; and you would print out response.body from the original call that failed. Did you try to remove Future.delayed?

Answer (score 0):

Remove last `return response;` and unnecessary `Future.delayed`. Something like this could work:

```
  Future<http.Response> _getAPIById(String pathURL) async {
    try {
      http.Response response = await _ioClient.get(
        Uri.http(ApiConstants.baseUrl, pathURL),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken!
        },
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 401) {
        await  refreshAccessToken();
        return await _ioClient.get(
          uri,
          headers: {
            HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
            'x-access-token': 'Bearer ' + accessToken!
          },
        );
      } else {
        return response;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Error occurred');
    }
  }
```